# Visual Studio Script Eval Windows showing outdated/wrong code

Tags: visual-studio

Developing a web app in Visual Studio 2022.

When debugging, I have Chrome DevTools open with "Disable Cache" checked.

When the app runs, VS opens scripts in Script Eval windows.

However, as I edit/save/refresh, even with "Disable Cache" checked in the browser, and even if I refresh the page with Ctrl-F5, these script eval windows are showing code that is several "save and reloads" ago.  As if VS, or perhaps IIS Express has it's own cache that ignores the browser's "disable cache" setting.

How can I fix this, or, if possible tell VS not to debug in these Eval windows and instead debug in the actual JavaScript source code in the editor window?

[image]

**I change the code, delete the breakpoint and replace it with a console.log() instead, then refresh the page with Ctrl-F5**

[image]

[image]